# SimpleInjector RegisterAll lazily

Tags: simple-injector

With SimpleInjector I can easily register multiple instances of a concrete type like so:

```
var config = MyConfig.Load("myconfig.xml");
this.container.RegisterAll<IFoo>(config.FooNamesToCreate.Select(name => new Foo(name)));
```

The downside of this is that all instances of `Foo` will be created right away during registration at the start of the application.

How can I register all theses instances of the same concrate type `Foo` **but defer the creation/instantiation of them until the first request of `IEnumerable<IFoo>`** ?

IMHO I'd need something like this:

```
foreach(var name in config.FooNamesToCreate)
{
    var nameToUse = name; // probably needed for closure
    this.container.AddRegistration<IFoo>(() => new Foo(nameToUse));
}
```

The solution for this I could come up with is abstract factory, but I wonder if there is a built-in way in SimpleInjector.

Comment: Can you supply an example of how you would typically use the ienumerable<ifoo>

Comment: I would ctor-inject the `IEnumerable<IFoo` into `Bar` and there do things like  `this.foos.ForEach(foo => this.WriteValue(foo.Name, foo.GetSomeValue(arg)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The downside of this is that all instances of Foo will be created
>   right away during registration at the start of the application.

Nope, this is incorrect.

There are two types of collections, what Simple Injector is concerned. Container-controlled collections and container uncontrolled collections. Container-controlled means that Simple Injector is in control over the creation, auto-wiring, and lifetime of the instances of a collection. Container-uncontrolled means that you supply an IEnumerable to Simple Injector, and it will basically just inject that `IEnumerable<T>` as-is into any consumer.

Your registration with `RegisterAll<IFoo>(config.FooNamesToCreate.Select(name => new Foo(name)))` is container-uncontrolled, because you will call `RegisterAll<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`. In other words, Simple Injector will not iterate that collection for you. Only if you call `container.Verify()`, Simple Injector will iterate it. So when you call `RegisterAll<IFoo>(config.FooNamesToCreate.Select(name => new Foo(name)))`, what happens is that the `FooNamesToCreate` property is called and the `Enumerable.Select` method is called to wrap the `FooNamesToCreate` property return value with a select enumerator.

But perhaps you want behavior that is even more lazy, for instance because:

- You don't want `config.FooNamesToCreate` to be called during application start-up, or
- you don't want the enumerable of `Foo` instances to be enumerated when `Verify()` is called.

In that case, you can do the following:

```cs
var config = MyConfig.Load("myconfig.xml");
container.RegisterSingle<IEnumerable<IFoo>>(
    () => config.FooNamesToCreate.Select(name => new Foo(name)));
```

What this does is register an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` as a singleton (which is basically the same as what `RegisterAll<IFoo>` does), but since you supply a delegate, you can let the collection itself be resolved lazily. When doing this, you will lose verification support that Simple Injector gives you when calling `Verify()`, which might be exactly what you want.

Do note though that even though we call `RegisterSingle`, the result will be an `IEnumerable<IFoo>` that will produce new instances of `Foo` everytime that enumerable is iterated. If you want the `Foo`s to be singletons as well, just call `.ToArray()` after the `Select(name => new Foo(name))`.